# Main Bower files

Tags: node.js, gulp, bower, gulp-concat

In my angularjs app, i try to concat bower file because i have to many lib. I make a task for concat file, here is code

```
var filter = require('gulp-filter');
var mainBowerFiles = require('gulp-main-bower-files');
var dest = 'dist/scripts';

gulp.task('main-bower-files', function() {
return gulp.src('./bower.json')
.pipe(mainBowerFiles([[filter, ]options][, callback]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));
});
```

After i call this task in nodejs cmd, i get this error in chrome console

```
.pipe(mainBowerFiles([[filter, ]options][, callback]))
```

This is error in node cmd

```
    .pipe(mainBowerFiles([[filter, ]options][, callback]))
                                ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Liftoff.handleArguments       (C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:116:3)
at Liftoff.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:198:16)
at module.exports (C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\liftoff\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:17:3)
```

If someone know solution??? Thnx

Answer (score 0):

i fix this with another library, called BOWER-FILES.

```
var lib    = require('bower-files')();
gulp.task('bower_js', function () {
gulp.src(jsBowerFile)
.pipe(concat('bower_js.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
.pipe(ngmin())
.pipe(uglify({mangle: false}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));
});
```